# UIButton on cell from dynamic table displaying wrong image

Tags: dynamic, uitableview, scroll, uibutton

I've created a custom cell with a `UIButton` to use as a checkbox. When pushed I change the button image to a checked checkbox. What happens is that if I check any of the checkbox when I scroll some other cell that had not been checked appears checked. I'm guessing I'm dequeing a cell with the checkbox marked and reusing it. I can't figure out how to set the images correctly. I've created an array of images to save the state of the images from each button but that isn't working. Here's my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Celula de Bebidas";

    MeuChurrasTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.precoTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell.nomeLabel.text = [nomeBebidasAlcoolicas objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //nome da bebida
        cell.precoTextField.text = [precoBebidasAlcoolicas objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.checkboxButton setImage:[imagemBebidasAlcoolicasCheckbox objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        cell.nomeLabel.text = [nomeBebidasNaoAlcoolicas objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.precoTextField.text = [precoBebidasNaoAlcoolicas objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.checkboxButton setImage:[imagemBebidasNaoAlcoolicasCheckbox objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    // identifica cada botao para depois saber qual foi presssionado.
    [cell.checkboxButton setTitle:cell.nomeLabel.text forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

    return cell;
}
```

By the way, if I try

```
if (cell == nil)
```

it never goes inside the if for some reason, even when the table is called for the first time.

Here is the code used to set the UIButton's image:

```
- (void)checkboxPressed:(UIButton *)sender onCell:(MeuChurrasTableViewCell *)cell
{
    NSIndexPath *cellPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
//    NSLog(@"%@ clicked", [nomeBebidasAlcoolicas objectAtIndex:cellPath.row]);
    if ([sender isSelected]) { //Botao nao selecionado
        [sender setImage:unselectedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setSelected:NO];
        [self.brain.bebidasSelecionadas removeObject:sender.titleLabel.text];
        if (cellPath.section == 0)
            [imagemBebidasAlcoolicasCheckbox insertObject:unselectedImage atIndex:cellPath.row];
        else
            [imagemBebidasNaoAlcoolicasCheckbox insertObject:unselectedImage atIndex:cellPath.row];            
    } else { //Botao selecionado
        [sender setImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [sender setSelected:YES];
        [self.brain.bebidasSelecionadas addObject:sender.titleLabel.text];
        if (cellPath.section == 0)
            [imagemBebidasAlcoolicasCheckbox insertObject:selectedImage atIndex:cellPath.row];
        else
            [imagemBebidasNaoAlcoolicasCheckbox insertObject:selectedImage atIndex:cellPath.row];
    }
}
```

Any help?